# What is the purpose of <: :>?

Tags: c

In an answer to another question, someone jokingly mentioned using `<: :>` instead of `[]` for array subscripting.  I had never heard of this, and apparently neither has Google, so I did a bit of testing and found that all the way back in C compilers, `<:` is interchangable with `[` and `:>` is interchangable with `]`, IE:

```
int* ptr;
ptr<:0:>;
ptr<:0];
ptr[0:>;
```

All compile and mean the same thing.  What was the purpose of this operator?

Comment: To be able to use array syntax in ancient terminals that were not capable of outputting the bracket characters.

Comment: When C was invented in the 70s. keyboards weren't standardized yet, so some keyboards didn't have all the keys. It probably is another example of that.

Comment: Because it is so much more readable thant `ptr??(0??)`?

Comment: @sashoalm: the trigraphs were an invention of ISO (ANSI) C to deal with the fact that European code sets used the code points for characters such as `[]{}` for national alphabetic characters.  Digraphs were a later invention (1994 Amd 1, IIRC) for a limited subset of the same job.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs gives a good history and list of digraphs and trigraphs in C and C++.